# loading a data.table object saved locally as an R object on Linux

Tags: r, linux, data.table

I have a file that creates and saves a data.table as an r object on a linux server:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(col1=c("a","a","b"),col2=1:3)
save(dt,file="./dt")
rm(dt)
```

If I load, later, this object and try to use it, I get an error message as if it wasn't a data.table, even if the class seems properly maintained:

`sudo Rscript -e 'load("./dt"); class(dt); dt[col1=="a"]'`

> "data.table" "data.frame" Error in `[.data.frame`(dt, col1 ==
>   "a") : object 'col1' not found
>   Calls: [ -> [.data.frame 
>   Execution halted

I had to turn it into a data.table explicitly to avoid the issue.

`sudo Rscript -e 'load("./dt"); dt<-data.table::as.data.table(dt); library(data.table); dt[col1=="a"]'`

Is that expected for some reason?

Comment: You have to load `data.table` library before using `data.table` syntax . Add `library(data.table)` before `load("./dt")`

Comment: Please don't use images where you only need to display text, which can then easily be indexed.

Comment: Check functions `saveRDS()` and `readRDS()`.  You do *not* want `save()` and `load()`.

Comment: yup adding library(data.table) did the trick thanks @PoGibas. I think I'm missing something obvious because it seems fine to *not* load the data.table library and then do indexing on a data.table object, as long as it happens in the file where the data.table is created. Like this: `dt<-data.table::data.table(col1=c("a","a","b"),col2=1:3); dt[col1=="a"]`

Comment: The `data.table` class inherits from the `data.frame` class, so without loading the `data.table` library, data.tables are treated as data.frames.

Comment: sorry if I'm thick, when I do this `dt<-data.table::data.table(col1=c("a","a","b"),col2=1:3); dt[col1=="a"]`, am I "loading the data.table library"? If I don't call `library(data.table)`, I can't use functions like `as.data.table()` without specifying `data.table::as.data.table()` afterwards, so it's not really "loaded"... or is it? Maybe it's a terminology thing.

Comment: you are loading but not attaching

Comment: Oh well. Somehow I never realized that a package is loaded even if not attached when one uses constructions like `data.table::data.table()`. It's all clear now, thanks everybody for not giving up on me. @PoGibas do you wanna answer the question so I can give you credit? or should I answer it myself? I just delete it because the answer is so obvious once you know that there's no need to attach a package to load it. What's the etiquette there?